# How to apply an opacity to a scatter plot flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [charts_flutter](https://github.com/google/charts) to draw a scatter plot.
So far, this is the relevant code I  wrote:

```
class _VennState extends State<VennDiagramWidget> {
  List<charts.Series<VennCircle, int>> circlesList;

  static List<charts.Series<VennCircle, int>> _createRandomCircles() {
    final circles = [
      VennCircle('red', 1, 50, 0.8, 'Venn1', 15, 35),
      VennCircle('black', 2, 150, 0.5, 'Venn2', 18, 20),
      VennCircle('green', 3, 200, 1, 'Venn3', 25, 25),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series(
        id: 'circles',
        data: circles,
        domainFn: (VennCircle venn, _) => venn.x_value,
        measureFn: (VennCircle venn, _) => venn.y_value,
        colorFn: (VennCircle venn, _) {
          if (venn.circleColor == 'red') {
            return charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault;
          } else if (venn.circleColor == 'black') {
            return charts.MaterialPalette.black;
          }
          return charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault;
        },
        radiusPxFn: (VennCircle venn, _) => venn.circleSize,
        domainUpperBoundFn: (VennCircle venn, _) => 50,
        domainLowerBoundFn: (VennCircle venn, _) => 0,
        measureUpperBoundFn: (VennCircle venn, _) => 50,
        measureLowerBoundFn: (VennCircle venn, _) => 0,
      ),
    ];
  }

  scatterPlot() {
    return new charts.ScatterPlotChart(
      circlesList,
      animate: true,
      primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        showAxisLine: false,
        renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
      ),
      domainAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        showAxisLine: false,
        renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I couldn't find a way to change the opacity of each circle. (each circle can have a different opacity)
I came across this [Opacity widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) but I wasn't able to apply it - probably because it should be used on a widget.
On that note, how can I define `VennCircle` as widget and not an object?

EDIT: I was able to do that simply by modifying the `colorFn` function:

```
colorFn: (VennCircle venn, _) {
          if (venn.circleColor == 'red') {
            return charts.Color.fromOther(
                color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                    Color.fromARGB(100, 255, 0, 0)));
          } else if (venn.circleColor == 'black') {
            return charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color.fromARGB(95, 0, 0, 0));
          }
          return charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color.fromARGB(95, 0, 255, 0));
        },
```

Comment: Set the alpha component of the color you are returning in `colorFn` to something other than 255.

Comment: @Abion47 Could you elaborate on how to do that?